# Error con "control null" al intentar cambiar una imagen con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

A ver si alguien que puede iluminar

Llevo todo el día liado con la forma de cambiar una imagen al hacer click en otra mediante javascript, pero a la hora de llamar a un elemento del documento, me arroja el valor null

Tengo el id = "UnoUno" en la imagen del documento HTML;

Al hacer click en ella, mediante el evento onclick, envío por parámetro el id de la imagen y la posición que ocupa, en éste caso sería "UnoUno" y "0"

En la función que recibe el evento onclick intento hacer referencia a la imagen en la que hice click para cambiarla por otra, y siempre recibo null

```
let ele = "#" + elemento; //resultado: "#UnoUno"
let control = document.getElementById(ele); //control: null
```

Llevo con éste error unas cuántas horas, he buscado, leído, releído y no consigo dar con el error que estoy causando

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Parte del fichero afectado HTML:

```
 <body>
     <main>
         <section class="section">  
              <table class="table">
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <img id = "UnoUno" class="img" src="./img/reverso.png" alt="imagen11" onclick="abrirImagenClick('UnoUno', '0')">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </section>
     </main>
 </body>
```

Parte del fichero afectado CSS

```
.table tr td img:hover
{
    border: 3px solid #fe0101;
}

.img
{
    height: 150px;
    width: 110px;
}
```

Parte afectada del fichero javascript

```
//recibo por parámetro con el evento onclick, el elemento cliqueado y la posición que ocupa
function abrirImagenClick(elemento, posicion)
{
    //variable que concatena el elemento con la almohadilla
    let ele = "#" + elemento;
    //variable que debería de almacenar el elemento del documento donde deseo cambiar la imagen
    //pero me devuelve null
    let control = document.getElementById(ele);
    imagen = document.createElement("img");

    imagen.src = "img/" + barajaBarajada[posicion];

    //control.appendChild(imagen);
}
```

Comment: Pon esto: `let control = document.getElementById(elemento);` porque el `#` sobra en un **getElementById**

Comment: como te dijeron usar el simbolo # buscando por id es redundante. El metodo ya aclara que busca un id entonces no es necesario usar #

Comment: Pues muchas gracias. Madre mía, un día entero buscando el problema y no tenía ni idea de que estaba pasando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) espera el ID de la etiqueta pero tu le agregas `#` al comienzo por lo tanto falla.

Debes agregar el `#` cuando escribes un selector CSS.  Por ejemplo la función [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) sí lo requiere.

```js
function mostrarTexto(){
    byId = document.getElementById("texto")
    selector = document.querySelector("#texto")
    console.log(byId.value)
    console.log(selector.value)
}
```

```html
<input id="texto" value="Hola" type="text"/>
<input type="button" value="Imprimir" onclick="mostrarTexto()"/>
```

Comment: Pues muchas gracias. Madre mía, un día entero buscando el problema y no tenía ni idea de que estaba pasando.

Answer (score 1):

Como te señalaron en los comentarios. getElementById no va con #. Pero además es que no necesitas buscar la imagen por la id, ya que la puedes enviar directamente en el evento usando this

```
<img class="img" src="./img/reverso.png" alt="imagen11" onclick="abrirImagenClick(this,0)">
```

```
function abrirImagenClick(imagen, posicion)
{
    imagen.src = "img/" + barajaBarajada[posicion];
}
```

Comment: Pues muchas gracias. Madre mía, un día entero buscando el problema y no tenía ni idea de que estaba pasando.